# Fastest Linux IDE with Find&Replace

Tags: php, ide, netbeans, aptana, geany

I'm looking for a fast IDE for Linux that has Find&Replace. I'm currently using Geany and I've tried NetBeans, and Aptana doesn't have a PHP plugin for 2.0. I prefer one that has a sense of projects. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: vi doesn't have a sense of projects, and it also doesn't have a GUI or syntax highlighting.

Comment: vi does have a sense of projects: http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/164-Vim-Productivity-Tips-for-PHP-Developers.html

Comment: Oh wow...that's pretty good. I'll have to take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gvim with at least the NERDTree, dbext and Taglist plugins. superfast.

Comment: How do you launch the graphical version from command line?

Comment: with "gvim" if you have it installed. under RedHat/Centos/Fedora it's in the vim-X11 package.